# Sorting a List of objects by the First element but if Equal sort by the second

Tags: java, sorting

I have to sort a list of objects. I have to sort the list by the value time, however, if the time of two or more events is equal, then I have to sort it by its type.
All I am looking for is a simple solution, the one I know would not be simple and wouldn't include any already created classes for sorting.

The expected list order

```
#ID , time, type
5 1.1 Arrived
5 1.1 Scheduled
4 1.2 Arrived
3 4.1 Arrived
2 5.4 Arrived
1 6.0 Arrived
5 61.1 Terminated
4 61.1 Scheduled
4 121.1 Terminated
```

The list I have:

```
#ID , time, type
5 1.1 scheduled
5 1.1 arrived
4 1.2 arrived
3 4.1 arrived
2 5.4 arrived
1 6.0 arrived
4 61.1 scheduled
5 61.1 terminated
4 121.1 terminated
3 121.1 scheduled
```

Have a look at the code to get the things better:

```
private List<Event> createEventList(List<Process> processList) {
        List<Event> list = new ArrayList<Event>();
        Event event;
        for(Process pr : processList) {
            // arrived
            int id = pr.getID();
            double time = pr.getArrivalTime();
            eventtype type = eventtype.arrived;
            event = new Event(id, time, type);
            list.add(event);

            //terminated
            time = pr.getFinishTime();
            type = eventtype.terminated;
            event = new Event(id,time,type);
            list.add(event);

            //scheduled
            time = pr.getFinishTime()-pr.getBurstTime();
            type = eventtype.scheduled;
            event = new Event(id,time,type);
            list.add(event);

        }
        list = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Event::getTime))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return list;

    }
```

EDIT: Event class and enum

```
public class Event {

    private int pID = 0;
    private double time = 0.0;
    private eventtype type = null;
    public static enum eventtype{
        arrived,
        scheduled,
        terminated,
    }

    public Event(int pID, double time, eventtype type) {
        super();
        this.pID = pID;
        this.time = time;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return pID + " " + Math.round(time*10)/10.0 + " " + type.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Just create your own Comparator and use it where you have Comparator.comparing(...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `thenCompare()` to compare second field and  no need to use `stream()` and `collect()` again since you are assigning result in same list

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Event::getTime).thenCompare(l ->l.getType().ordinal()));
```

Since you order by type which is an enum change the order in enum declaration for sort by `.ordinal()` otherwise you need to define comparator by own.

```
public static enum eventtype{
    terminated,
    arrived,
    scheduled,
}
```

Comment: The output has not changed. No idea why. Also, if more events have the same time, priority 1 is terminated, then arrived than scheduled

Comment: How you want to sort your enum ? share your `eventtype` enum

Comment: Updated check now

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the output stayed the same. Nothing changed, it doesn't react to .thenComparing(...) at all. I tried to shuffle enum order to test and again nothing changed

Comment: Are you using `.thenCompare(l ->l.getType().ordinal())` in sort ?

Comment: It does work, my bad. the values were not the same, I have a problem with Math.Max(), it changes the values. thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can use Comparator#thenComparing to compare by the second object after comparing the first.

```java
list = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Event::getTime).thenCompare(Event::getType))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: The output has not changed. No idea why. Also, if more events have the same time, priority 1 is terminated, then arrived than scheduled